# Can't install tensorflow with conda package manager. Pip3 not found and virtualenv not compatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

Trying to install tensorflow on OSX with python installed with anaconda :

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation

Get stuck on :

sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp35-none-any.whl

and get error :

tensorflow-0.7.1-cp35-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

When I try virtualenv installation

New python executable in /Users/xxx/tensorflow/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/xxx/tensorflow/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/xxx/tmp' (should be '/Users/xxx/tensorflow')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable

What's the best way to install tensorflow with python installed with anaconda?

Comment: I had the same issue running python 3.4  and pyenv to create my virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to install with `python 3.4.3` and `pip 8.1`.

```
 $ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow
  tensorflow-0.7.1-cp35-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

To fix I simply upgraded to `python 3.5.1` (I use pyenv to allow installation local of multiple versions of python).

Running with `python 3.5.1` I can now successfully execute:

```
$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp35-none-any.whl
 ...happy install message fun follows....
```

I have no clue as to why python 3.4.3 fails, but this version of tensorflow https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl seems to work with python 3.4.3 fine.